# ASP.NET Web Application with Windows Authentication not working inside Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

Build an Intranet site which is mapped to the sub domain address under Windows Authentication hosted on web server (Windows Server 2012 IIS 8).Authentication works fine when tested outside the web serve which is also under the same domain.

**ISSUE:** Unable to authenticate my application inside web server using the sub domain address though it prompt of User name & password but does not authenticate because of which it does not resolves external style sheet & Images.

Following are the current setting for ASP.NET Web Application

1. Web site Address: SubDomain.Domain.xx\SubSite
2. Application Pool using Integrated Windows Authentication
3. IIS 8 Authentication setting: ASP.NET Impersonation & Windows Authentication status enabled
4. Using default IIS port
5. IIS binding:  To the default port mapped to SubDomain.Domain.xx with unsigned
6. IIS binding: To the default port mapped to Blank with Hosted Server IP address.

Please advice what setting I am missing to sort the issue..

Comment: You may need to implement a custom membership provider: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are logging in with the domain, e.g. yourdomain\yourusername.

You could then do with a test page which shows who it thinks you are (Identity). It may be running as the application pool if it's not quite set up right and that account probably doesn't have access to other resources that it needs.

Does your web browser console confirm that this is the error and not just an incorrect path to the files?

Comment: Thanks McGaz  for your reply.I have logged in as web Admin which is domain account. When I try to access the site, n Windows login pop-up but after entering the domain user name & password does not authenticate. But if the same thing I do from the client machine (outside web server) it works.

Comment: Are you definitely adding the domain in when it prompts for the user/pass? It is probably trying to authenticate with a local machine account. Can you authenticate with your account whilst on the server?

Comment: To be more specify the ASP.NET Application which is mapped to the following Host Name Services.companyname.CountryDomain with ASP.NET Impersonation & Windows Authentication enabled is unable to authenticate the AD user when prompted for credentials. This happens only when I try to browse the website inside the Application Server using the host name but works fine when accessed from the client desktop.
Thanks.

Comment: Same issue for me. Trying to authenticate in a WebForms app with Windows Authentication, but it does not function. Web Server does not get the identity of the user, no matter of using user name string or Domain/User name string.